# Duplicate Value SQL

Tags: sql

I need to select the project name "Projeto1", but I have two of them, since I have a users table that are not allowed to insert more that one project with same name, if I create a project in other user with a same name that other project on another user has, I can't select the one "Projeto1" if anyone could help me I appreciate!

[image]

Comment: It may help if you reword, perhaps providing an example of the user table and examples of the result you would like to get.  I'm just not sure what you're asking for at the moment.

Comment: ok, i can explain more, i have a table for Users and in there i insert Projects, i am making an application in vb, and if i insert a duplicate Project in some user, it gives me an error, BUT, if i change my user and try to insert a project with the same name that the previous user, it will allow to do that because there is no project with that name in the current user, the problem is that i want to make a SELECT of my project name, and like you can see above, i have that two "Projeto1" , so how can i do it to insert the same project in other user and select the project of the user?

Comment: What I think I'm reading is that given a specific user, you want only their projects or given a user and a project to search for, you only want the row that matches that user:
SELECT * FROM UserProject WHERE ID_utilizador = 7 AND nome_projeto = 'Projeto1'

Comment: ok thx its solved

Comment: @GonçaloGrilo can you add your own answer as to how this was solved? Others who might visit your question will find it valuable to see a solution. You can also mark your own answer as accepted to put closure to your question.